# App Registry Not Ready while upgrading to Django 1.11 from 1.8

Tags: python, django, django-1.11, django-upgrade

I'm facing this issue while upgrading to Django version 1.11.
Here's the list of errors what I'm getting for Djagno auth user model.

```
File "/customer/models/customer.py"
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
File "/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py"
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
File "/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py"
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
File "/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py"
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
File "/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py"
    self.check_apps_ready()
File "/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
```

I've tried get_user_model() in the place of "import User" but got the same "AppRegistryNotReady('Apps aren't loaded yet.')" error.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Edit: After adding Djagno.setup() after installed apps list. I've got this error:
`RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: unfortunately no.